# Final Cut Pro 7: Zoom without using “scale”

Tags: final-cut-pro

Here's what I want to do:

I have footage witch I want to divide into several different squares at the same time (think "24"), while also cropping the footage so that I can show certain parts of the original material. All this I can do with the "crop" and "scale" functions under "motion". However, I would also like to zoom in, within one of these frames, during the video. If I use scale for this, the whole frame gets bigger. That's not what I want.

I've circumvented the problem by creating a white square, placed it on a video track higher in the hierarchy than the one I want to manipulate, then using color key to let the footage shine through the white parts. However, this isn't especially confortable to use, especially since I haven't found any good way to feather the edges of the box.

Comment: Have you tried using keyframes under the motion tab?

Comment: @Colum Yes, I do work with keyframes, but the question here is what parameters I should automate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this all the time. It's super easy:

1. Set up the 'shape' of your frame with the crop tool.
2. Apply the effect 'Basic 3D' (Effects > Video Filters > Perspective > Basic 3D).
3. In the controls for that effect, use the 'Scale' parameter to zoom your image. It will not affect your crop marks!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The scale attribute will only impact the items on a given layer. Of the box you want to scale I on it's on layer in the timeline, you should be able to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get this answer. Could you expand a little on it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can **make the square feather on photoshop** first, and then import the solid already with the feather. (less render time)

You can also **render the video** with the **scale** movement first, **export**, **re-import** this export, then **crop** exactly where u want with the scale zoom already made it.

Just my 2 bits. =) Hope it helps.

Also, probably in After Effects you get faster results on this type of composition.

Answer (score 0):

duplicate the clip to be scaled, on top of the original clip. Use crop to crop out everything except the bit you want to scale up. If necessary move the anchor point for this layer so that it's in the centre of the part that gets blown up, then scale it up.